# Change EnvironmentName in IIS (vNext MVC6)

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to use MVC6 and I want to use new feature "Changing configs by environment" in my apps

So as far as I understand I can choose proper config by changing environment variable ASPNET_ENV. I know two ways to change value of this variable

1) I change variable at Debug tab at Project Properties

2) I change variable at Azure Portal for my Azure Web Site

But how can I specify this variable in IIS after publishing website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set specific user for the AppPool of your website, and then set environment variable for the user.